# Reference request for Frobenius numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

The Frobenius number of a set of coprime integers is the largest number that not can be written as the sum of integer multiples of numbers in that set.

I'm looking for a general reference on Frobenius numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a book by Jorge L. Ramírez Alfonsín called The Diophantine Frobenius Problem.

Comment: That's seems like a sufficient reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

See also:

J.C.Rosales, P.A.García-Sánchez. Numerical Semigroups. Springer, 2009.

J.Amos, I.Pascu, V.Ponomarenko, E.Trevino, Y.Zhang. The Multi-Dimensional Frobenius Problem. *Involve*, **4**(2) 2011, pp.187-197.

Comment: J.Marklof, The asymptotic distribution of Frobenius numbers, Inventiones ${\bf 181}$ 179-207 (2010).